# When a line bundle on a projective variety separates tangent vector?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, line-bundles

In the Huybrecht's book Fourier Mukai transform in Algebraic geometry, in order to prove Bondal and Orlov's results (proposition 4.11), it seems that he uses following things.

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically close field, $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $k$. $L$ is a line bundle on $X$ and $x$ is a closed point $X$. $k(x)\cong k$ is the residue field and $i: x\hookrightarrow X$ is the closed embedding.
Then he claims two things:

> 1: A closed subscheme $Z_{x}$ of $X$ with length 2 concentrated in $x\in X$ is one to one correponds a nontrival element of $\mathrm{Ext}^{1}(i_{*}(k(x)),i_{*}(k(x)))$.

> 2: $L$ separated the tangent vectors at $x$ if and only if $H^{0}(X,L)\to H^{0}(X, \mathcal{O}_{Z_{x}})$ induced by the restriction map is surjecitive for all $Z_{x}$ (closed subscheme of length 2 concentrated in $x$).

First, I do not know what is the restriction map $L\to \mathcal{O}_{Z_{x}}$ in the claim 2. I think the first claim just means a tangent vector at $x$ is one to one correponds a closed subscheme of length 2 concentrated in $x$. Could you give me some ideas how to prove these two claims?

Comment: For 2), my first thought is that there is a natural restriction map $L \to L_{Z_x}$, and then perhaps he composes with the isomorphism $L_{Z_x} \to \mathcal O_{Z_x}$. But without having the proof in front of me it's hard to tell *why* he would do the latter.

Comment: Or I guess *an* isomorphism of stalks.

Comment: I think we should first prove claim 1. Only we know what subschemes of length 2 look like, we could describe the restriction map.

Comment: @MathAttack if you're going to edit an older post, it's worth fixing more than just one character. There's a lot of other stuff you could improve here from a copyediting standpoint.

Comment: @KReiser Yes I know but I started correcting only grammatical errors. I'm trying not to overdo it so as not to annoy, in fact I do 3-4 every 6 hours or so (I was correcting the most common errors like "hiperbolic", "tangant", "elipse", "matix", "polinomial", "intergral" etc...)